# WPF - collapsing grid cells

Tags: wpf, button, size, width

I'm having some problems with the layout of buttons on a screen. There are a number of buttons with the visibility set to collapsed depending on certain criteria.

Anyway, with the buttons sitting in a stackpanel, the contents determine the width of the buttons. Because these should share the same size, I put them in a grid where the columns are using the SharedSizeGroup.

Having done this, buttons now all share the same width, the smallest width needed to display the button with the largest content. What it does mean though is that buttons don't display at the required position.

That is - assume five buttons in columns 0-4 where the first button is collapsed, buttons should ideally all shift to the left so that they always occupy space left to right. Is there any way I can accomplish this or, if not, how can I get buttons in a stackpanel to share the same width?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your buttons with individual grids and use that to set a shared size, the scope should be the stackpanel. Then control the visibility of the individual grids instead of the buttons, this is a bit messy though.

Edit: This is probably what you need:

```
    <UniformGrid Rows="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            ...
```

Comment: Tried the one grid with individual grids within these - the visibility of the individual grids collapse depending on the criteria that used to be placed on the buttons. This doesn't work though as they share the same size and so if any of the buttons are visible, all other cells will still occupy the same space...

Comment: You should not create a grid around the individual grids, that defeats the purpose, you need to place the individual grids inside a stack panel.